# Does an Enum exist for Asc or Desc ordering?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an Enum natively in .NET for asceding or Desceding ordering?

I need to use the ordering concept in different libraries, and I want loose coupling as possible.

Comment: I think he actually means an Enum. It sounds like he just wants something to use for sort directions (ie when used as a parameter) if its already out there in the Fx somewhere.

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek "there is only two options" is never a valid excuse to use a boolean.  Booleans store true and false.  They are ambiguous for anything else -- including genders, ascending vs descending, etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- [SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder.aspx) in System.Data.SqlClient
- [ListSortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in System.ComponentModel

Comment: Correct Answer! What's the better (maybe atomic, simple) library to use? I'll use this in a interface for repository, so SortOrder is a better bet?

Comment: Judging by @andrecarluccis excellent answer `ListSortDirection` is better if you only want Ascending/Descending - because of availability on more targets.

Comment: I would say ListSortDirection as well, since the other is tied to SqlClient.

Comment: Note that although `SortOrder` lives in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace, it is defined by the System.Data assembly and readily available for a broader audience.

Answer (score 70):

There are more than 8 sorting enums in .NET. It goes to show, even at Microsoft engineers will re-invent the wheel. It's also interesting how wildly the commenting practices and code style varies.

Here are the ones I've found:

1. [System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/ListSortDirection.cs)

   ```
   public enum ListSortDirection {
       /// <devdoc>
       ///    <para>Sort in ascending order.</para>
       /// </devdoc>
       Ascending,
       /// <devdoc>
       ///    <para>Sort in descending order.</para>
       /// </devdoc>
       Descending 
   }
   ```
2. [System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder)

   ```
   public enum SortOrder {
       Unspecified     = -1,
       Ascending       = 0,
       Descending      = 1
   }
   ```
3. [System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/DLinq/Dlinq/SqlClient/Common/SqlNode.cs#947090c99399bed9)

   ```
   internal enum SqlOrderType {
       Ascending,
       Descending
   }
   ```
4. [System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.DirectoryServices/System/DirectoryServices/SortDirection.cs)

   ```
   public enum SortDirection
   {
       //
       // Summary:
       //     Sort from smallest to largest. For example, A to Z.
       Ascending,
       //
       // Summary:
       //     Sort from largest to smallest. For example, Z to A.
       Descending
   }
   ```
5. [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SortOrder.cs)

   ```
   /// <include file='doc\SortOrder.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="SortOrder"]/*' />
   /// <devdoc>
   ///    <para>
   ///       Specifies how items in
   ///       a list are sorted.
   ///    </para>
   /// </devdoc>
   public enum SortOrder {

       /// <include file='doc\SortOrder.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="SortOrder.None"]/*' />
       /// <devdoc>
       ///    <para>
       ///       The items are
       ///       not sorted.
       ///    </para>
       /// </devdoc>
       None = 0,

       /// <include file='doc\SortOrder.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="SortOrder.Ascending"]/*' />
       /// <devdoc>
       ///    <para>
       ///       The items
       ///       are sorted in ascending order.
       ///    </para>
       /// </devdoc>
       Ascending = 1,

       /// <include file='doc\SortOrder.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="SortOrder.Descending"]/*' />
       /// <devdoc>
       ///    <para>
       ///       The items are
       ///       sorted in descending order.
       ///    </para>
       /// </devdoc>
       Descending = 2,

   }
   ```
6. [System.Web.Helpers.SortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.sortdirection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

   ```
   public enum SortDirection {
       Ascending,
       Descending
   }
   ```
7. [System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/UI/WebControls/SortDirection.cs)

   ```
   public enum SortDirection {


       Ascending = 0,


       Descending = 1

   }
   ```
8. [System.Xml.XPath.XmlSortOrder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/Xml/System/Xml/XPath/XPathExpr.cs#84cf1ab39c7fe8e7)

   ```
   public enum XmlSortOrder {
       Ascending       = 1,
       Descending      = 2,
   }
   ```
9. [System.Data.Common.EntitySql.AST.OrderKind](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/EntitySql/AST/QueryExpr.cs,68f04768e5fe32ef,references)

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Represents order kind (none=asc,asc,desc).
   /// </summary>
   internal enum OrderKind
   {
       None,
       Asc,
       Desc
   }
   ```

**Edit: Another has arrived since this was originally posted.**

10. [System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.DataVisualization/Common/DataManager/DataSeries.cs,9f30d16e24ec888e)

    ```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sorting order (Ascending or Descending).
    /// </summary>
    public enum PointSortOrder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ascending sorting order
        /// </summary>
        Ascending, 

        /// <summary>
        /// Descending sorting order
        /// </summary>
        Descending
    }
    ```

Comment: Also note that although `SortOrder` lives in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace, it is defined by the System.Data assembly.

Comment: Looking over these i think the DirectoryServices option is best if you assume an order must exist. If you want to understand the concept of natural order then the SqlClient one is superior. However I don't know why anyone would bother ultimately sending the message "order Foo by not ordering in any specific fashion"... maybe if you wanted unspecified to mean shuffled results, that would be reasonable.

Comment: Looking closer at this again, I just realized that's Active Directory services not like file system directory. SqlClient's SortOrder is in .NET Core and so is XmlSortOrder. Apparently there's really no good choices if you don't want the Unspecified sort included in SqlClient's

Comment: I personally prefer ListSortDirection over the others for generic purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I went with `ListSortDirection` as it's one of the few (or the only) one that doesn't require an additional package as it's in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

[SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder.aspx) and [ListSortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are two valid choices but keep in mind this:

[ListSortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

- available in .net verions 1.1 to 4 and silverlight.
- the sort order is mandatory: ListSortDirection has only "Ascending" and "Descending" options so the user has too choose one of them.

[SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder.aspx):

- available only in .net versions 3.5 and 4. No support for silverlight.
- sort order is optional: you also have the "Unspecified" option.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting point relating to [Windows.Forms.SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscy145f.aspx) and [Data.SqlClient.SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder.aspx)

Upon inspection the first has values:

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    None = 0,
    Ascending = 1,
    Descending = 2,
}
```

while the second has values:

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    Unspecified = -1,
    Ascending = 0,
    Descending = 1,
}
```

Probably a good idea to be consistent, especially if serialising.

Answer (score 2):

There are two that I know of: 
**[SortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sortdirection.aspx)** and **[SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscy145f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**

One quick caveat is that those are found in the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and `System.Windows.Forms` namespaces, respectively, so there's the possibility that they might not apply for what you're doing *semantically*.

Comment: you are right. But as you think this is semantically wrong, cause I don't have reference to UI or Forms in those libraries.

Comment: I'm thinking in something inside System perharps.