# Better way to accomplish sorting a Generic List of IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

We're using Entity Framework and a "POCO" generator to create our types that get passed around to various layers and they belong to the (changed to protect the innocent) namespace Company.Application.Project.Module.  These POCO objects all inherit from a base class that handles some basic stuff for us.

I would like to write a function that can take a collection of these objects and sort them, by property name.

I have written the following function -- which does the gist of what I want to do, but I don't like it for a few reasons:

1)  This won't work on any object type, it has to be an object type that the SortHelper class is aware of (hence the last using statement).

2)  The "POCO" objects' Type and BaseType seem to be inconsistent -- depending on from where you call this function within the app (unit test project vs. called from a presenter object of our MVP app) which causes problems with the line I've bolded, because if it grabs the wrong Type, the Property won't be on it, in the following line.

From the presenter object, the .GetType is showing up as:
ClassName_96D74E07A154AE7BDD32624F3B5D38E7F50333608A89B561218F854513E3B746
...within the System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies namespace.

This is why the code says .GetType().BaseType on that line, which gives me:
ClassName
...within Company.Application.Project.Module

But within the unit tests, the .GetType() is showing up as
ClassName in Company.Application.Project.Module

and BaseType is showing up as
BaseClass in Company.Application.Project.Module

...which makes more sense, but I don't understand the inconsistency -- and the inconsistency scares me.

3)  Hate using Reflection to do this in general.

If anyone has a better way of doing this, or even a fix to make the Reflection behave with the namespaces/types -- I would certainly appreciate it!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using Company.Application.Project.Module;

namespace Company.Application.Project
{
    public static class SortHelper
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool descending)
        {

            // bail out if there's nothing in the list
            if (source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (source.Count() == 0)
            {
                return source as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
            }

            // get the type -- or should it be the BaseType?  Nobody knows!
            Type sourceType = source.First().GetType().BaseType;

            // this works fine _assuming_ we got the correct type on the line above
            PropertyInfo property = sourceType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (descending)
            {
                return source.OrderByDescending(e => property.GetValue(e, null));
            }
            else
            {
                return source.OrderBy(e => property.GetValue(e, null));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use a .Net [Enum for the sort direction instead of a bool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6372606/209259).

Comment: You can use `ObjectContext.GetObjectType` to get the actual underlying type of the proxy

Comment: Just turn off proxies if you don't want them. `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`. Or get the underlying type as above.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ever try `Type sourceType = typeof(T);`?

Comment: >But within the unit tests, the .GetType() is showing up as ClassName in Company.Application.Project.Module. Let I guess, in your real code you are using some smart ORM mapper; but in your unit tests you are using some fake of repository? That can be reason of inconsistency, cuz ORM mappers creates proxies on your objects.

Comment: So, well, there is nice solution. Cuz you have some BaseClass, you you can do that: while (type != typeof(object) && type.BaseType != typeof(BaseClass)) type = type.BaseType

Comment: And I have advice for you - don't use reflection like property.GetValue/property.SetValue. That's slow. Try to create expression and compile it, there a lot of tutorials about it.

Comment: @nsinreal - clever idea about the base classes -- I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that there's no good reason to do this at all. You're using the `OrderBy` extension method in your function, why not just call that instead of this function? Unless there's something that isn't shown in your example, the function isn't doing anything other than figuring out how to call `OrderBy` (or `OrderByDescending`) and then calling it.

If it's just that you want to use a boolean flag to switch between ascending and descending order (without having to use an if statement every place you are trying to sort something), then I would *strongly* suggest the following method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool descending = false)
{
  if (descending) return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
  else return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

It's neat and clean, you still get to use a lambda expression to define the key without any requirement for a dependency to your model, you get to (optionally) change the sort order to descending using a boolean flag, and NO REFLECTION. That's a WIN WIN WIN! ;)

[Begin edits in response to comments]

OK, so now that I've got VS2010 running again, I was able to figure out a way to encapsulate the SortExpression used when sorting an ASP.NET GridView control, as promised. So here it is.

Since we don't have a model defined for this question, I'm just going to create a simple one.

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
  public decimal TotalPurchaseAmount { get; set; }
  public string Comments { get; set; }
  public bool Shipped { get; set; }
  public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

So then let's assume we have a CustomerDetails.aspx page that we want to add a GridView to that would list out the Orders.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
  AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvOrders_Sorting">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" SortExpression="OrderID" HeaderText="Order ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" SortExpression="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPurchaseAmount" SortExpression="TotalPurchaseAmount" HeaderText="Total Purchase Amount" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" SortExpression="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Shipped" SortExpression="Shipped" HeaderText="Shipped" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind, there is a static dictionary object:

```
protected static readonly Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Order, object>>> sortKeys = new Dictionary<string,Expression<Func<Order,object>>>()
{
  { "OrderID", x => x.OrderID },
  { "OrderDate", x => x.OrderDate },
  { "TotalPurchaseAmount", x => x.TotalPurchaseAmount },
  { "Comments", x => x.Comments },
  { "Shipped", x => x.Shipped }
};
```

And then here's the function that handles sorting:

```
protected void gvOrders_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
  string exp = ViewState["gvOrders_SortExp"] as string;
  if (exp == null || exp != e.SortExpression)
  {
    e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    ViewState["gvOrders_SortExp"] = e.SortExpression;
    ViewState["gvOrders_SortDir"] = "asc";
  }
  else
  {
    string dir = ViewState["gvOrders_SortDir"] as string;
    if (dir == null || dir == "desc")
    {
      e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
      ViewState["gvOrders_SortDir"] = "asc";
    }
    else
    {
      e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
      ViewState["gvOrders_SortDir"] = "desc";
    }
  }
  if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
  // There's a MyCustomer property on the page, which is used to get to the Orders
  { gvOrders.DataSource = MyCustomer.Orders.OrderBy(sortKeys[e.SortExpression]); }
  else
  { gvOrders.DataSource = MyCustomer.Orders.OrderByDescending(sortKeys[e.SortExpression]); }
  gvOrders.DataBind();
}
```

There, that does it.

I admit that the `gvOrders_Sorting` method is really messy, but that's the nature of using custom sorting with the `GridView`. It could be further encapsulated, but I decided to keep it simple. (I actually started working on creating a helper class that would handle sorting and paging, but custom paging in .NET 4.0 is an even worse beast than custom sorting is!)

Hope you like it. ;)

[Correction]

I just noticed an issue with the code as written. `MyCustomer.Orders` would be a `List<Order>` not an `IQueryable<Order>`. So either change the `sortKeys` to be a `Dictionary<string, Func<Order, object>>`, or change the call to `MyCustomer.Orders.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortKeys[e.SortExpression])` or to `MyDbContext.Orders.Where(o => o.Customer == MyCustomer).OrderBy(sortKeys[e.SortExpression])`. I leave the choice to you. ;)

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention that the check on `source.Count()` to see if it equals 0 will result in the query being compiled and executed.

Comment: There are many reasons he would want to use a string to represent the field.  Perhaps his UI allows the users to sort the results, and he doesn't want to map every single field to an ordering function.   This also would save the work of updating the code everytime a field is added/removed/updated.

Comment: @JaceRhea - I acknowledge that there might be cases where it might be more convenient to use a string in a particular situation. I do think however that allowing a user to type in the name of a property (or even click a button that only knows the name of the property because that is what its Text property is set to) is a bad idea in general. Code shouldn't penetrate into the UI, nor should users be allowed to execute arbitrary code. Such sorting needs can be much more appropriately handled through encapsulation.

Comment: @JaceRhea - You said, "This also would save the work of updating the code everytime a field is added/removed/updated." That is actually a benefit because magic strings should be avoided wherever possible. Refactoring a property name is a trivial thing when using lambda expressions, but when it is being referenced as a string, it doesn't get refactored and then you have use the text search to find all occurrences on that property name in the entire project (even worse if it's a project used in multiple solutions).

Comment: I was just pointing out there are use cases, so maybe it isn't wise to assume the user is incorrect in what they are asking for. Let's save the encapsulation lecture for when someone actually asks.

Comment: @JaceRhea - Acknowledged and agreed. Let's wait to see what the OP is really needing. ;)

Comment: Hey guys -- appreciating the discourse on the subject.  The problem in question is that this is an ASP.NET app, so we have various UI Entities defined (for example, a gridview) that have columns defined by property name -- and these are strings, defined in the markup of the .aspx file. for example (obv. shorthand)  `<asp:gridview id="foo" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false"><columns><asp:BoundField DataField="ShortName" SortExpression="ShortName" HeaderText="Name" /></columns></asp:gridview>`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no better way to tightly bind them to property names of a strongly typed object, like you could in a Winforms app -- but it'd be cool if I'm mistaken!

Comment: @Cortright - I see. Thanks for clearing that up! ;) I'm in the middle of repairing my install of VS2010, but when I get it back up and running, I'll look and see if I can find a better answer for your situation. I'm assuming you would rather not use a `switch` statement, am I right?

Comment: So when you click the header of one of these columns, it's firing an event that looks like this:
`protected void gvListing_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)` where `e.SortExpression` is a string (defined as above in the markup of the gridview and corresponding to whatever property name of the list of objects the grid is bound to) -- unfortunately since we're stateless, I'm having to re-fetch the data in situations like this, then sort it.

Answer (score 2):

If they all inherit from a base-class, why not constrain the generic argument?

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool descending) where T : MyBase
```

This way, the compiler won't *let* you pass a class to this function that does not inherit from `MyBase`, and you're out of the "nobody knows?!" territory :)

Comment: This is a good suggestion and I have done so -- but it's still not altering the weird behavior I listed under Item 2) above, because what is going on is:

T is a ....
MyClass_96D74E07A154AE7BDD32624F3B5D38E7F50333608A89B561218F854513E3B746 : MyClass : MyBase

Answer (score 1):

Just project the property to be sorted:

```
 public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Sort<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, U> sortExpr, bool descending)

...


source.OrderBy(e => sortExpr(e));
```